# Problem visualizing Kinect data

Tags: kinect, rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-fuerte-desktop-full on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM guest on an iMac OS 10.7.4 host. I have 3d acceleration set for the vm in VirtualBox.

I have tried the steps found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33165/visualizing-kinect-output-without-a-turtlebot/) and neither worked for me.

I also tried suggestions found [here](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=47592&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=39), with no luck.

When running openni_launch, I get numerous errors of the form:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

I also get a "service already advertised" error

```
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [5040]
[ERROR] [1342713651.658142929]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1342713651.673904205]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

and some calibration warning, but I don't think they're the problem

```
[ WARN] [1342713653.543366768]: Camera calibration file /root/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00362821517049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1342713653.544051626]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1342713653.544360723]: Camera calibration file /root/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00362821517049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1342713653.544473754]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

However, I do see that the Kinect is found because:

```
[ INFO] [1342716950.352185341]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1342716950.354223440]: 1. device on bus 001:03 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00362821517049A'
[ INFO] [1342716950.356082261]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1342716950.562713795]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:3 with serial number 'A00362821517049A'
[ INFO] [1342716950.686668429]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1342716950.686886788]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame'
```

After creating my PointCloud2 display in rviz, it shows "Status: Warning" and "Points
Showing [0] points from [0] messages" and "Topic No messages received".

Following instructions to open the data in image_view does not work for me, either.

Help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39281/problem-visualizing-kinect-data/) by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not aware of the current state, but openni used to not work in virtual machines.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on 2012-07-20**:
http://blog.charlesdietrich.com/2012/02/ros-openni-kinect-on-virtual-machine.html

**Comment by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on 2012-07-20**:
I just found this post, and now I believe you are correct. Apparently it just won't work on VM at the moment. I guess I'll have to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes setting the Target Frame and Fixed Frame in rviz to be the camera's frame helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ankush](https://answers.ros.org/users/2890/ankush/) with karma: 75 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on 2012-07-20**:
Do you mean setting fixed frame to /camera_depth_optical_frame, like it says in the tutorials I linked above? If so, I've already tried that.